# Swift: Remove object from array if timestamp is within certain range of previous timestamp?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects that contain a timestamp. I want to drop all the objects that are in 6 hours chunks. Eg, reducing the following [Obj(00:00), Obj(04:00), Obj(06:01), Obj(07:00), Obj(12:00)] to [Obj(00:00), Obj(06:01), Obj(12:00)].

How would I go about this?

The object is a CoreData object that ends up as follows:

```
struct Entry {

var intensity: Float?
var timestamp: Date?

}
```

Comment: is this a 12hr or 24hr timestamp?

Comment: Good one, thanks. 24h.

Comment: And also here you need to mention a sample reference of your timestamp object structure and how you are setting the timestamp in that object i.e `String` or `Date`

Comment: You can use `reduce(into:_)` for instance. But a simple for loop should do the trick. You create an output empty array of `Obj`, you iterate the current array, compare the current `Obj` with the last `Obj` in the new array, if it's valid (more than 6h), you append, else, you skip it. So you need a "comparison", are you able to compare them? Have you tried something?

Comment: Is `Obj(00:12)` on the "next day"?

Comment: No, it's a 24h clock. So Obj(00:12) is noon.

Comment: Aren't the time stamp sorted? Noon isn't 12:12, 00:12, is midnigh, no?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. It's a typo and I can't read. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple for loop:

```
var withForLoop: [Entry] = []
for anEntry in initialArray {
    // If it's empty, we add it if there is really a timestamp
    guard let lastEntry = withForLoop.last, let lastEntryDate = lastEntry.timestamp else { withForLoop.append(anEntry); continue }

    // If there is no timestamp, we skip it
    guard let currentEntryDate = anEntry.timestamp else { continue }
    // Here I took hours in "absolute", meaning, I don't consider a change of hour (saving time)
    // Create your own comparison if needed
    if currentEntryDate.timeIntervalSince(lastEntryDate) > 3600 * 6 {
        withForLoop.append(anEntry)
    } // Else, there was less than 6 hours difference, we don't append it
}
print(withForLoop)
```

With a `reduce(into:_)`:

```
let output = initialArray.reduce(into: [Entry]()) { partialResult, current in
    // If it's empty, we add it if there is really a timestamp
    guard let lastEntry = partialResult.last, let lastEntryDate = lastEntry.timestamp else { partialResult.append(current); return }

    // If there is no timestamp, we skip it
    guard let currentEntryDate = current.timestamp else { return }
    // Here I took hours in "absolute", meaning, I don't consider a change of hour (saving time)
    // Create your own comparison if needed
    if currentEntryDate.timeIntervalSince(lastEntryDate) > 3600 * 6 {
        partialResult.append(current)
    } // Else, there was less than 6 hours difference, we don't append it
}
print(output)
```

Warning:

- I assume the entries to be sorted.
- I used 3600 * 6 for the calculation, but it might no be "correct". It depends on what you want to do. It doesn't manage the "hour saving" for instance.